# Ref property 'focus' undefined in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

```
public divContainer: HTMLElement;

componentDidMount(){
  this.divContainer.focus()
}

buildRef = (e) => {
  this.divContainer = e;
}

render() {
  return (
    <div ref={this.buildRef}></div>
  )
}
```

In the above code I'm getting a ref of the div and adding focus to it in componentDidMount. But when I run the test it says `Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined`. Doesn't ref run BEFORE componentDidMount? If so, then why this error?

Please note that the actual component renders and works as expected. It's just the test that fails. I also found a solution and that is to wrap `this.divContainer.focus()` in this `if (this.divContainer)` condition.